# Use angular routing on Express framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am new with Angular and Node/Express. Now I've setup a node/express server where I want to use angularjs on. I came as far as loading the main index.jade. I have some hrefs on this page that I want to use angular for to route between these links, but I can't seem to get it working. The console keeps telling me that the page that I'm linking to does not exist.

This is the app.js which is the server in express

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is the index.js on express

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the jade file with my layout

```html
doctype html
html(ng-app='myApp')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js')
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/app.js')
    base(href="/")
  
body
    block content

div(ng-view)
```

This is the angular routing

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/red', {
            templateUrl: '/views/red.jade'
        }).when('/green', {
            templateUrl: '/views/green.jade'
        }).when('/blue', {
            templateUrl: '/views/blue.jade'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

This is the error I get in the console

```js
GET http://localhost:3000/views/blue.jade 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12578
q @ angular.js:12323
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12075
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16843
$digest @ angular.js:17982
$apply @ angular.js:18280
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14250
hg @ angular.js:3734
d @ angular.js:3722
angular.js:14516 Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Fviews%2Fblue.jade&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:19933
    at angular.js:16843
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17982)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18280)
    at l (angular.js:12378)
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.onload (angular.js:12532)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14516
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11004
(anonymous) @ angular.js:19937
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16843
$digest @ angular.js:17982
$apply @ angular.js:18280
l @ angular.js:12378
v.onload @ angular.js:12532
```

Answer (score 0):

You should render Jade templates on the server side, Angular don't know anything about Jade and how to work with it.

Setup Angular routing so that it does not contain "jade" extension

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/red', {
        templateUrl: '/views/red'
    }).when('/green', {
        templateUrl: '/views/green'
    }).when('/blue', {
        templateUrl: '/views/blue'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And modify index.js in that way

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.get('/views/red', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('red', { title: 'Express red' });
});
router.get('/views/green', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('green', { title: 'Express green' });
});
router.get('/views/blue', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('blue', { title: 'Express blue' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

So now when Angular requests template by path "/views/blue" it sends request to Express server and in accordance with routes defined in index.js proper template will be rendered.

Comment: Thanx, I already figured it out for myself. But thank you for your help